# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am getting this exception from the following VB.NET code for only certain months:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

It happens on the line:

```
If CDate(dRow("CompleteDate")).ToString("d") = arrWeekYear(i, 1).ToString("d") Then
```

If I understand this correctly, then the problem is I am trying to compare some NULL values for CompleteDate to a non-NULL value.

How do I fix this?  For some dates, this code above runs perfectly.  However for some of the more recent records, it does not.  But I am able to get output from the T-SQL query with same date range and there are no errors; it runs quickly also.  And I examined this T-SQL query for both "Date_Completed" and "Review_Date" NULL values, but either way, "CompleteDate" was always = NON-Null value.  So I do not understand how this is happening.

Here is my VB.NET query:

```
            commandstring = "SELECT Batch_Records.Part_Number, Batch_Records.Lot_Number, Batch_Records.Date_Received, " & _
                "IsNull([Date_Completed], [Review_Date]) AS [CompleteDate], Batch_Records.Error, " & _
                "Batch_Records.[Group], Batch_Records.MFG, Batch_Records.MFG2, Batch_Records.QC, Batch_Records.QC2, " & _
                "QC_CODES.CODE_DESC, DATEADD(DD, 1 - DATEPART(DW, Batch_Records.Date_Received), Batch_Records.Date_Received) AS SundayDate " & _
                "FROM EXCEL.Batch_Records LEFT JOIN EXCEL.QC_CODES ON Batch_Records.Part_Number = QC_CODES.CODE_ID " & _
                "WHERE (Batch_Records.[Group]" & TheGroup & " AND Batch_Records.Date_Received > '" & FirstWeek & "' AND Batch_Records.Date_Received < dateadd(Day, 1, '" & LastWeek & "'))" & _
                   "ORDER BY Batch_Records.Date_Received"
```

When I add this line above the error-causing line above, my report times out for these months.  So what to do?

```
If Not dRow("CompleteDate") Is System.DBNull.Value Then
```

Comment: NOOOO!!  Don't use string concatenation to substitute values into your queries!  **Don't do it!**

Comment: He's right, with this code you can easily be sql injected !!!

Comment: In your query, is `EXCEL` the schema, or are you joining against an excel sheet somehow?  Or are we dealing with SQL only?

Comment: What is the datatype of the CompleteDate column?

Comment: +1 to David for explaining **[why it's so bad](http://xkcd.com/327)**!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check for null with dRow.IsNull("CompleteDate") before you ask for the value.

Or if this is 'supposed to be' impossible, change your query to never return rows where it can be null.

Comment: @Joel, I think the OP is using a DataRow, so the correct function is `IsNull`.  If it was a DataReader, you're right it would be `IsDBNull`.

Comment: Thanks Joel, but this does not work.  IsNull is not a recognized VB.NET function.  And I tried IsDBNull, but this caused a compile error cause it's not the right datatype.  Only way I see I can use IsDBNull is to do separate "If" statement as I explained above.  But that is timing out on me.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @OP, what is drow?  A DataRow?  This is the method I was talking about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0.aspx

Comment: So if you follow that link, you'll see that it is in fact a method, but you're calling it wrong.  Try `Console.WriteLine(drow.IsNull("FirstName"))`

Comment: Thanks guys, I added this now but it is still timing out.  And I increased the dataset timeout to 12000, but it is still timing out.  Let me know if u have any other ideas.  (I also tried selecting just top 1000 rows and then it finishes).  There definitely are some NULL date values in this date range though, based on my SQL query results

Answer (score 0):

I use a sub (different for each datatype) to get data from a Datareader, using the index instead of the name though:

```
#If Access Then
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
Friend Function GetDbStringValue(ByVal Dr As OleDbDataReader, ByVal nr As Integer) As String
#Else
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
Friend Function GetDbStringValue(ByVal Dr As MySqlDataReader, ByVal nr As Integer) As String
#End If
    If IsDBNull(Dr.Item(nr)) Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return Dr.GetString(nr).TrimEnd
    End If
End Function
```