# check if Date is null and if so, insert a new value

Tags: vb.net, date

I have a `Class Property` called `PasswordDate`.  It's being updated via a stored procedure.  `PasswordDate` is a `Date`, not a `DateTime`.  It's returning null and VB.Net is throwing an error:

**`Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.`**

It's throwing an error every place I use `PasswordDate` in my StackTrace.

This is my test user and the column `PasswordDate` was just created, so my user doesn't have a date for that column.

So, what my plan is, check to see if it's null, if it is, make `Password = Date.Now()`

I have tried:

```
If (PasswordDate Is Nothing) Then
```

Also:

```
If Date.TryParse(ua_PasswordDate_, passwordDate) Then
```

I have looked at these SO questions: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392499/conversion-from-type-dbnull-to-type-date-is-not-valid-on-tryparse) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696737/conversion-from-type-dbnull-to-type-date-is-not-valid)

Comment: Which is the line that throws the error?  What are the types of the variables on that line?

Comment: let me update the question

Comment: It's not clear why those questions you linked didn't help you.

Comment: What is `PasswordDate` and where did it come from?

Comment: Updated, hopefully it's a little more clear

Comment: @KevinFischer: Given the information provided, it would seem that the error is being thrown when you try to set a value from the database (which happens to be `NULL`) to the `PasswordDate` field, but I don't see where you're doing that.  Either way, that's where the problem is.  You need to check if the database field is `NULL`, not if `PasswordDate` is `NULL`.

Comment: Note that `DbNull` and `Nothing`/null are not the samething.  A DB Query can return `DBNull` when there is no data for the field.  Nothing means the object is not initialized.  (still unclear since we have no context - the error is coming from where you poll the DB fields, not the class property).

Comment: ..........I'm a huge idiot.  But thanks to y'all, you guided to find it correctly.  Thank you all for walking a slowpoke through

Comment: The Right Thing to do is to also upvote the linked answers since they do properly explain the problem

Comment: I think I did already, but I'll double check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a value from a database is null you can use `IsDBNull()`, and it works for date variables as well:

```
If IsDBNull(PasswordDate) Then
    '....
End if
```